# .VBS scripts have stopped running... No idea why!

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vbscript, task-scheduler, windows, msxml

We have two **.vbs scripts** that are run by our **Task Scheduler** that have suddenly stopped working for no reason we can fathom. We haven't significantly altered our system configuration in the last 24 hours, and the scripts have run without a hitch for months.

According to the Task Scheduler the scripts just keep running and never stop, which is never the case. I stopped all running versions through the Scheduler and manually attempted to run one of the .vbs scripts. I got the following error message:

> Line: **15**
>    Error: **The system cannot locate the resource specified.**
>    Code: **800C0005**
>    Source: **msxml3.dll**

Line 15 (or 16 to be more accurate - line 15 itself is blank, but so is line 1) is: **xml.Send**

Would could have suddenly caused this? Looking in `system32\` and `sysWOW64\` shows that **msxml3.dll** exists.

Anybody got any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is it trying to send to?  the [xml.send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763706%28VS.85%29.aspx) method is used to make a http/https request.  The error indicates it can no longer make the request.  Perhaps the server is down or something has been changed.  Try and open up a web browser and manually connect to the server the script is trying to access.

Comment: Woot! Our IIS bindings had been altered meaning the script couldn't find the site it was looking for. A few quick changes and it's running perfectly again. I was barking up completely the wrong tree! Thanks for your help.